# Is it possible to store local data with PhoneGap / Windows Phone 7 Mango?

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

Is it possible to store local data with [PhoneGap - Windows Phone 7 Mango](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-wp7) at the moment?

I read that the File API is still under development and local and session storage aren't possible at the moment because of the lack that the IE9 doesn't support access to these when running without domain?

So no way to store local data? Have to wait for the next PhoneGap WP7 version? When will that be? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is not supported currently by phonegap, you can easily implement Isolated Storage support for your WP7 Phonegap app.

[BrowserExperiments](http://peppy.browserexperiments.com/) has a tutorial on how to do so.

Download the [windows phone 7 phone gap tutorial](http://peppy.browserexperiments.com/learn/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/phonegap-wp7.docx) here and go to the section titled:
**Isolated storage implementation in PhoneGap**

Comment: Please note that the linked document is incredibly out of date with regards PhoneGap development for WP7

Answer (score 4):

**Update** **:** By using phonegap1.3 you can implement localstroage & sessionstorage in WP7.